# Are there any risks on using 'single-transaction' and 'extended-insert' on mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, import

I'm new in db administration and I've looked for a faster import of a mysqldump.

I had a db with about 1.1 million rows and mostly InnoDB tables and wanted this to import on a managed server. Before I used the standard mysqldump command for dumping the db. At import I had a write speed of about 60.000 rows per hour which was extremly slow.

I searched for a way to speed thingsup and found a post here saying to use --single-transaction and --extended-insert on mysqldump. Now the dump is importing in under 30 seconds.

After a quick overview it seems that the data is correctly imported but I'm a little bit leery about the fast import.

Why is this soo fast after adding these two options?
Are there any disadvantages on using this options?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: extended-insert is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way is faster because

- Server does not need to perform fsync() multiple times during data import. fsync is the operation of submitting data into disk
- Extended insert enables sequential write to disk which means disk does not need to seek for a locations for every row.
- If the table has Auto_Increment values, Server can spare adequate values for the batch insertion at once rather than once for every insertion.
- The extended insert builds batch INSERT statements (many rows per INSERT). That inherently speeds things up 10-fold because of amortizing the statement overhead (Added By @Rick James in comments)

I know two side effects for this method.

1. undo log will get too large while performing this operation.
2. If an error happen during the operation, the entire import will be reverted (which might be an advantage in your case).

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you for your good explaination. I didn't understand the tech-speak at the mysql docs.

Comment: Correction.  The extended insert builds batch `INSERT` statements (many rows per `INSERT`).  That inherently speeds things up 10-fold because of amortizing the statement overhead.  There is no downside of this option unless you happen to had some setting (max_packet_size?) set to low during the load.

Comment: @RickJames is this a correction or an addition? If it's a correction, do u mean sequential write to disk is not correct?

Comment: `INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ...` does not change the I/O, it makes the parsing and processing more efficient.

Comment: I know that bulk insertion from a file or another table is a sequential write and normal insert is a random write (which might be buffered in innodb to perform sequential write). Knowing that, I am assuming extended insert is also a sequential write without a need of buffer. I do agree with parsing and processing efficiency and i will add it to my answer. Please give me a reference if I am wrong. Tnx

Comment: The "sequential" versus "random" depends the order in which the rows are fetched.  InnoDB rows are fetched (and written to dump) in `PRIMARY KEY` order.  So the reload will also be in that order, _whether or not_ extended-insert is used.  This is very efficient for the PK and the data.  Secondary keys are built in bulk (note that the dump disables and enables keys), so they are reasonably efficient.

Comment: @RickJames:  even though mysqldump disable/enable keys , it applies to only myisam engine not innodb.

Comment: @RickJames:if you mention innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 1 , extended insert changes the I/O right. Please let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: Setting that to 1 is the "safest" -- a crash at any instant will allow for full restore.  2 gives better performance (sometimes a lot better), but with the risk of losing 1 second's worth of COMMITs.

Comment: I think "extended-insert" leads to much faster load.  Check the dump for "start transaction" and "commit" and "autocommit=1".  Even without the transaction speedup, the parsing of 1000 INSERTs is 10 times as slow as parsing 1 INSERT with 1000 rows in it.  (That is, even MyISAM speeds up.)